# index.php is bypassed in wordpress local install

Tags: wordpress, apache, url, redirect

hello I have a local wordpress installation, which is a copy of my hosted website.
i'm going to try to make it simple :

If i type "http://mylocalwebsite/index.php", it works and shows me my local copy

If i type "http://mylocalwebsite", index.php is still used, but i'm ending in my hosted web page (www.myrealsite.com)

If i type "http://mylocalwebsite" again, it doesn't use index.php, and directly opens my hosted website.

All hosts files are correct, none of them is leading to my hosted website.
I've done a search for "www.myrealwebsite.com" in the directories of the local copy : no result.

I just don't understand why. Any ideas ?

Thx

Comment: This is a cached redirect from the browser you are using (since the hostname you are using is not FQDN, the browser tries to correct that, or has previously seen a (301) redirect to the real webpage like from non-www hostname, to a www.hostname and uses that to assume what is correct). If you try the same with CLI curl request, I would imagine the result will be as you expect.

Comment: thank's for your answer
I think you're right.

Comment: Ah, I should've posted this as an actual Answer.. so I get my points :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a cached redirect from the browser you are using (since the hostname you are using is not FQDN, the browser tries to correct that, or has previously seen a (301) redirect to the real webpage like from `non-www hostname`, to a `www.hostname` and uses that to assume what is correct).

If you try the same with CLI `curl` request, I would imagine the result will be as you expect.